# ESLint to remove unnecessary braces on React properties?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

Is there any way to get ESLint to automatically flag/fix properties in JSX which have an unnecessary curly brace?

```
<HStack mt={"xl"} ... />
```

...would become...

```
<HStack mt="xl" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with `'react/jsx-curly-brace-presence'`.

(Thanks to the person who downgraded the post without comment - you're a gentleman and a scholar)